# Why should I double declare a variable in a ViewModel class when using LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Right now I am following a tutorial where I am developing a simple game app trying to understand and use MVVM app architecture. In my ViewModel class I have a field which contains the score of the player.

The score variable is declared like this:

```
private val _score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val score: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _score
```

Now, in my UI Controller class, I observe the score like this:

```
viewModel.score.observe(this, Observer { newScore ->
        binding.scoreText.text = newScore.toString()
    })
```

So, my question is why do I need the second declaration of score? Can't I just have a

```
val score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
```

and observe it like above? I tried and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work. The point of doing that is to make sure that changes to that variable only occurs from one place, being your ViewModel. It's just a pattern people have followed to make it easier for you to debug and ensure that state of your app/view is correct. One [source from Google](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data#5) I found here, although I'm sure there are plenty more